# How does TLS handshake work in a load balanced system?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, haproxy, rancher

We are using rancher docker orchestration tool: it is using HAProxy for enabling load balancing.
I am wondering how how a hanshake is processed if a new HTTPS connection to a service is established.

Is the the handshake done between client and the load balancer (rancher/HAProxy) or will the load balancer just forward the HTTPS requests to the backend service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends [how you configure it](https://serversforhackers.com/c/using-ssl-certificates-with-haproxy).

- **SSL Termination** the handshake is done by the load balancer.
- **SSL pass-through** the handshake is done by the backend.